# Check the values in the array has a split element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to check whether the array variable hold a single value or it contains more then one value which is separated by comma. when i obtain the array variable with more than one value I use the split() method to obtain each value separately, whereas if the array value holds a single value it shows error in the split method.. Here is my code which i have tried to overcome this problem. hence i didn't get the expected output..

Thanks in advance..

```
var temp = new Array();
if (temp = benefitid1.split(',')) {
    //Code here
} else {
    temp = benefitid1;
}
```

Comment: There is a difference in `=` and `==`

Comment: So benefitid1 is an array with single element or a string?

Comment: You should also update your question with the *actual* code. As it stands you have one syntax error and one typo

Comment: @jcubic: benefitid1 is an array with single element or may be a group of element separated with comma. for e.g it may be like benefitid1=2 or benefitid1=2,3,4

Comment: What is the value of benefitid1 ? benefitid1="2,3,4"; or benefitid1=['2','3','4'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery length api . find the below example:

```
var temp = new Array()
var benefitid = [1,2,3].toString()
temp = benefitid.length > 1 ? benefitid.split(','):benefitid
```

The jquery length api is used to calculate array length so we can easily find how many no values placed in array.

Answer (score 1):

Convert array to string using javascript. You missed out `==` for if statement

```
if (temp.toString() == benefitid1){

}
```

suppose for example

```
temp = ['1','2','3'].toString();
benefitid1  = '123';
```

the above if condition be

```
if('123' == '123'){
   return true;
}
```

Comment: don't need `benefitid1.split(',')` you can directly use `toString` on array

Comment: @JqueryKing: At one condition i need to check whether the value is not separated with comma. For eg: benefitid1=2 and in other condition if it is benefitid1=2,3 then the if condition doesn't exceute the benefitid1=2 as it dosen't contain any split.. how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var temp = new Array();
 if (temp = benefitid1.split(',')) 
 {
    console.log(temp.length);
 }
 else
 { 
    temp = benefitid1;
 }
```

Comment: This code won't work, you are not casting `temp` against `benefitid1.split(',')`, you are reassigning its value, which is not what you want in an if statement. Check the difference between `=` and `==` and `===`.

Answer (score 0):

YOu just commented the if closing braces

```
var temp = new Array();
if (temp = benefitid1.split(',')) 
{
      //Code here
}
else
{ 
   temp = benefitid1;
}
```